# System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object - Why happening?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, objectdisposedexception

I got the error having the stack trace...

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Button'.
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PointToScreen(Point p)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

The code producing this error is....

```
Friend Sub GoHome(ByVal sender As Form)
  InTransit = True
  sender.Close()
  fMain.Show()
End Sub
```

It doesn't give error when I just switch the order of the .show and .close method

```
Friend Sub GoHome(ByVal sender As Form)
  InTransit = True
  fMain.Show()
  sender.Close()
End Sub
```

Can you please tell me why for the first case it gives error and why in second case it doesn't??

Comment: More interesting information….
1 I happens only when the application is virtualized (by Citrix)
It never happen if it run in the same computer.
2 when the code include a message box it doesn’t give the error.

This code works fine without any error…
Friend Sub GoHome(ByVal sender As Form) 
  InTransit = True 
  MsgBox(“Any message”)
  sender.Close() 
  fMain.Show() 
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Are `sender` and `fMain` the same object in this case?

If so... when you call `sender.Close` you're effectively calling `fMain.Close`, and the `Close` method will be disposing that object behind-the-scenes. If you subsequently call `fMain.Show` then you're calling it on an object that you just disposed, hence the error.

**Or, alternatively...**

Maybe `sender` is one of the child controls on `fMain`?

You call `sender.Close`, disposing the child control. You then call `fMain.Show` which attempts to do *something* with the child controls belonging to `fMain`. The error occurs when it tries to do that particular something with the child control that you just disposed.